# Combine Grep Output based on the filename

Tags: shell

```
grep -ia '^Windows Installer' Galant01.txt Galant02.txt | awk -F '\t' '{print substr($1,1,index($1,":")) $4 "<br>"}' ;
```

The output produces:

```
Galant01.txt:Manual<br>
Galant02.txt:Manual<br>
```

It will be good to show instead:

```
Galant01.txt,Galant02.txt:Manual
```

The idea is to combine the similar input together and to leave the below intact:

```
Galant01.txt:Automatic
Galant02.txt:Manual
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe your output through this:

```
perl -e '@l=<>; chomp @l; map { /(.*?):(.*?)<br>/ and push @{$h{$2}}, $1; } @l; map { print join(",", @{$h{$_}}), ":$_\n"} keys %h'
```

Incorporating the `awk` part into this, here's the complete commandline:

```
grep -ia '^Windows Installer' Galant01.txt Galant02.txt | perl -e '@l=<>; chomp @l; map { /(.*?):(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*)/; push @{$h{$5}}, $1; } @l; map { print join(",", @{$h{$_}}), ":$_<br>\n"} keys %h'
```

Unfortunately it isn't short, so you could put it in a `filter.pl` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@l=<>;                                       # read all input lines
chomp @l;                                    # safely remove EOL
map {                                        # process input lines
   /(.*?):(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*)/;        # match grep output
   push @{$h{$5}}, $1;                       # add filename to hash
} @l;
map {                                        # process hash
    print join(",", @{$h{$_}}), ":$_<br>\n"  # print filenames and key
} keys %h
```

and use `grep -ia ..... | filter.pl`

Comment: grep -ia '^Windows Installer' Galant01.txt Galant02.txt | awk -F '\t' '{print substr($1,1,index($1,":"))  $4 "<br>"}' | perl -e '@l=<>; chomp @l; map { /(.*?):(.*?)<br>/ and push @{$h{$2}}, $1; } @l; map { print join(",", @{$h{$_}}), ":$_\n"} keys %h'
Galant01.txt,Galant02.txt:Manual

Comment: Where can I see why my correct answer got downvoted?

Comment: I am not very sure, I wasn't the one who did this.

Comment: (I didn't think so - just curious. Perhaps I'll gain that privilege sometime ;-))
As you can see, there's some postprocessing required to order the data as you need; I'm not sure it can be made to be much shorter..

Comment: So it is like putting filter.pl into a function. Base on your last edit. Thanks for breaking it down into parts as I wasn't sure about perl. I notice made some changes for : # match grep output to make it more versatile.

Comment: You're welcome - I never really learned `awk` as `perl` is far more versatile ;-) And ofcourse, you can modify the script to suit your needs. The essential part is collecting the data in the hash, which has as key the 4th field of the grepped files, and as value an array of filenames.

Comment: Hi Kenney, I tried an example but :  grep -ia '^Message Queuing down Level clients' kia0051 kia0053 | awk -F '\t' '{print substr($1,1,index($1,":")) $4 "<br>"}' | filter.pl
bash: filter.pl: command not found

Comment: You can skip the `| awk .. ` part. Be sure to `chmod 755 filter.pl` and check your `path` environment. Alternatively: `grep -ia '^Message Queuing down Level clients' kia0051 kia0053 | perl ./filter.pl`

Comment: kia0051:Automatic kia0071:Disabled kia0053,kia0061,kia0063:Manual

Comment: I got some output like the above can you help me change to :  kia0051:Automatic kia0071:Disabled <br> kia0053,kia0061,kia0063:Manual

Comment: (Missing semicolon on previous line?)
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at filter.pl line 11.

Comment: Updated code to add `<br>` right before `\n`, and remove the final `'`(left over from commandline)

Comment: filter() {
   perl -e '@l=<>; chomp @l; map { /(.*?):(.*?)<br>/ and push @{$h{$2}}, $1; } @l; map { print join(",", @{$h{$_}}), ":$_\n"} keys %h'
}

grep -ia '^Message Queuing down Level clients' $fileset | awk -F '\t' '{print substr($1,1,index($1,":")) $4 "<br>"}'  | filter

Comment: I manage to fixed the filter.pl issue by creating a function in unix and using unix to invoke function by grep -ia ... | filter

Comment: I don't see <br> printing anywhere in my output the one you fixed.